# Ruby plug in installation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I downloaded the `ruby` plugin for the sonarqube, and it is in the .rar file format.
I placed it in the `sonarqube/extensions/plugin` folder.
But when I'm running the sonar-scanner it is showing that **You must install a plugin that supports the language `ruby`**.

So what can I do?

Comment: `rar` is an archive. Depending on what OS you use, download the unarchiver from [here](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm), unarchive `rar` file and use it as intended.

Comment: thank you mudasobwa